# python easy_install failed because of wrong setuptools version

Tags: python, setuptools, easy-install

I tried to a library via easy_install like following:

```
$ sudo easy_install bbfreeze

Searching for bbfreeze
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/bbfreeze/
Reading http://systemexit.de/bbfreeze/
Best match: bbfreeze 0.97.2
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/b/bbfreeze/bbfreeze-0.97.2.zip#md5=16e4981f4d8abaff3053f89be436ac8d
Processing bbfreeze-0.97.2.zip
Running bbfreeze-0.97.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-Ti7cDj/bbfreeze-0.97.2/egg-dist-tmp-PqrogM
The required version of setuptools (>=0.6c11) is not available, and
can't be installed while this script is running. Please install
 a more recent version first, using 'easy_install -U setuptools'.

(Currently using setuptools 0.6c9 (/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg))
```

So I tried to upgrade setuptools to 0.6c12 but it has been already installed:

```
$ sudo easy_install -U setuptools

Searching for setuptools
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools/
Reading http://peak.telecommunity.com/snapshots/
Best match: setuptools 0.6c12dev-r85381
Processing setuptools-0.6c12dev_r85381-py2.6.egg
setuptools 0.6c12dev-r85381 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing easy_install script to /usr/local/bin
Installing easy_install-2.6 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c12dev_r85381-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for setuptools
Finished processing dependencies for setuptools
```

Just like this:

```
$ ls -l /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/
-rw-r--r--    1 some  staff  333775 11 13 23:59 setuptools-0.6c12dev_r85381-py2.6.egg
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel  328075  2  6  2010 setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg
```

I use Mac OS X 10.6.4. How can I fix this wrong reference of easy_install ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the newer version of `setuptools`, you need to use the newer version of `easy_install` installed by it.  Note the line:

```
Installing easy_install script to /usr/local/bin
```

Try this:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/easy_install bbfreeze
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I could install it!!